# Keep Button on Edge of sidebar

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sidebar, react-bootstrap

I am in working on a react template, and I want to have a sidebar navigation component. I am struggling with the expanding portion. So when the nav component expands I want the content to shrink and the expand/collapse button to stay on the edge of the menu.

### closed

[image]

### open

[image]

My idea was to use react-bootstrap and its Col component, but that did not work. My next idea is to keep track of the width of the sidebar menu and adjust the content and button accordingly. For this idea, I am thinking I need to pull up the width state to my top level component, but that seems sketch.  I am trying to figure out how to get the width of a component as it expands and shrinks. My experience is pretty low, this is my first on my own react project.

App.js (top level component)

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Route, NavLink, HashRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./Home";
import SidebarContainer from "./Sidebar/SidebarContainer";
import Row from "react-bootstrap/Row";

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <HashRouter>
        <div>
          <Row>
            <div className="header">
              <span>Company Name</span>
              <span>App Name Goes Here</span>
              <span>Hello Username</span>
            </div>
          </Row>

          <Row>
            <SidebarContainer/>
            <div className="content">
              <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            </div>
          </Row>
        </div>
      </HashRouter>
    );
  }
}
```

SidebarContainer

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ToggleButton from './ToggleButton';
import SidebarMenu from './SidebarMenu';

export default class SidebarContainer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      SidebarOpen: false
    };
    this.toggleSidebar = this.toggleSidebar.bind(this);
  }

  toggleSidebar(){
      this.setState({
          SidebarOpen: !this.state.SidebarOpen
      });
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <ToggleButton onClick = {this.toggleSidebar} menuVisibility = {this.state.SidebarOpen}/>
                <SidebarMenu menuVisibility = {this.state.SidebarOpen}/>

            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Sidebar menu

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./SidebarMenu.css";
import FeedbackButton from "./FeedbackButton";

export default class SidebarMenu extends Component {
    render() {
        let visibility = "hide";
        if(this.props.menuVisibility){
            visibility = "show";
        }

      return (
        <div id="SidebarMenu" className= {visibility}>
        <h2><a href="#">Home</a></h2>
        <h2><a href="#">About</a></h2>
        <h2><a href="#">Contact</a></h2>
        <h2><a href="#">Search</a></h2>
        <FeedbackButton/>
        </div>
      )
    }
};
```

Button

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./ToggleButton.css"

export default class ToggleButton extends Component {
    render() {
        let menuStatus = "hidden";
        let direction = ">"
        if(this.props.menuVisibility){
            menuStatus = "open"
            direction = "<"
        }

      return (
          <button id="toggleButton" className={menuStatus} onClick={this.props.onClick}> {direction} </button>
      )
    }
};
```

Comment: `I want the content to shrink and the expand/collapse button to stay on the edge of the menu` - you should check `flexbox`.

Comment: This looks promising. I am trying it now. I will let you know if it works.

Comment: It worked perfectly. I noticed that the react-bootstrap Row component overrides the flow-wrap to wrap, and once I changed that to no-wrap it worked perfectly. Thank you so much. @extempl

I am going to clean some things up and post the updated code in case someone else stumbles across this in the future.